# Wrapping JavaScript libraries to allow multiple versions without conflicts

Tags: javascript

**Background**

We currently use jQuery to dynamically add third-party JavaScript libraries to our main index.html file at runtime (this is extremely simplified, but should help in understanding). Once they're added, the browser handles downloading them.

I'm wondering if there is there a way via some JavaScript library (or homegrown way) to dynamically modularize or wrap the third-party JavaScript libraries so that two versions of the same library can be loaded without conflicts and can be referenced independently?

**For example:**

Version A of 'underscore.js' could be referenced as:

```
versionA._.noop()
```

Version B of 'underscore.js' could be referenced as:

```
versionB._.noop()
```

Thus allowing both versions of 'underscore.js' to be available, but not conflict with each other?

Comment: The first question is why would you ever need two different versions of the same library on the same page?

Comment: Great question. Our container SPA allows different teams to build their own "applications" that we render. Each application can include any JS libraries that *they* need. If two applications are loaded and each includes underscore, for example, then we'd like to allow this, but in a modular, scoped manner.

Comment: Erm, in that case, I don't think you can get a generic "JavaScript" solution. I'd just run each sanboxed in an IFrame or something, so they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: How are you loading each application into the wrapper spa? Making sure that each application's code is wrapped in a closure will ensure that they don't conflict with eachother. You would need to watch out for any libraries that add themselves as properties on the window object though.